# backbone.js and states that are not in models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In the data-driven paradigm of Backbone, the backbone views/routers should subscribe to model changes and act based on the model change events. Following this principle, the application's views/routers can be isolated from each other, which is great.

However, there are a lot of changes in the states of the applications that are not persisted in the models. For example, in a to-do app, there could be buttons that lets you look at tasks that are "completed", "not completed", or "all". This is an application state not persisted in the model. Note that the completion state of any task is persisted, but the current filter in the view is a transient state.

What is a good way to deal with such application state? Using a plain, non-backboned state means that the views/routers cannot listen to the changes in this state, and hence become difficult to code in the data-driven paradigm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *buttons filter example* can be properly solved using *Model events*.

I suppose your *buttons handlers* have access to the *tasks Collection*. Then filter the collection and trigger events over the *selected Models* like:

```
model.trigger( "filter:selected" )
```

or

```
model.trigger( "filter:un-selected" )
```

The *ModelView* can be listening to these events on its Model and acts accordingly.

This is following your requirements of respecting the not use or *"attributes that are not persistent"* like *selected* but I don't have any trauma to use special attributes even if they shouldn't be persistent. So I also suggest to modify the *selected* attribute of your Models to represent volatile states.

So in your *buttons handlers* filter the collection and modify the *selected* attribute in your Models is my preferred solution:

```
model.set( "selected", true )
```

You can always override `Model.toJSON()` to clean up before `sync` or just leave this *special attributes* to travel to your server and being ignored there.

Answer (score 0):

Comment got long so I'll produce a second answer to compare.

First, I feel like "completed", "not completed" are totally item model attributes that would be persisted. Or maybe if your items are owned by many users, each with their own "completed" "not completed" states, then the item would have a completedState submodel or something. Point being, while @fguillen produced two possible solutions for you, I also prefer to do it his second way, having models contain the attributes and the button / view doing most of the work.

To me it doesn't make sense for the model to have its own custom event for this. Sounds to me like a filter button would only have to deal with providing the appropriate views. (Which items to show) Thus, I would just make the button element call a function that runs a filter on the collection more or less directly.

```
event: {
    'click filterBtnCompleted':'showCompleted'
},
showCompleted: function(event) {
    var completedAry = this.itemCollection.filter(function(item) {
        return item.get('completed');
    });

    // Code empties your current item views and re-renders them with just filtered models
}
```

I tend to tuck away these kind of convenience filter functions within the collection themselves so I can just call:

```
this.ItemCollection.getCompleted(); // etc.
```

Leaving these attributes in your model and ignoring them on your server is fine. Although again, it does sound to me like they would be attributes you want to persist.

One more thing, you said that using plain non-backboned states sacrifices events. (Grin :-) Not so! You can easily extend any object to have Backbone.Event capabilities.

```
var flamingo = {};

_.extend(flamingo, Backbone.Events);
```

Now you can have flamingo trigger and listen for events like anything else!

**EDIT: to address Router > View data dealings -------------------//**

What I do with my router might not be what you do, but I pass my appView into the router as an options. I have a function in appView called showView() that creates subviews. Thus my router has access to the views I'm dealing with pretty much directly.

```
// Router
initialize: function(options) {
    this.appView = options.appView;
}
```

In our case, it may be the itemsView that will need to be filtered to present the completed items. Note: I also have a showView() function that manages subviews. You might just be working directly with appView in your scenario.

So when a route like /items/#completed is called, I might do something like this.

```
routes: {
    'completed':'completed'
},
completed: {
    var itemsView = ItemCollectionView.create({
        'collection': // Your collection however you do it
    });
    this.appView.showView(itemsView);

    itemsView.showCompleted(); // Calls the showCompleted() from View example way above
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response!
What I am asking is this: imagine the user types in "http://site.com/tasks#completed" and you now need to display all the completed tasks. How does your route handler inform your view?

Comment: It definitely helps; thanks. I see this approach a lot (and also the opposite approach - passing router to view and have the view listen to route events), but I believe both break the principle of separation of concerns where the router and the view should be isolated from each other.